# Prove that $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = 3-2x^3$ is continuous at $x=-4$

Tags: real-analysis

> Prove that $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = 3-2x^3$ is continuous at $x=-4$

I started the proof like this:

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given then I want to find a $\delta=\delta(\varepsilon) : |x-a| <\delta$ and $|f(x)-f(a)|<\varepsilon$.

\begin{align}
|f(x)-f(a)| &= |(3-2x^3)-(3-2(-4)^3|\\
&= |-2x^3-128|\\ &=2|x^3-64|\\ 
&= 2|x^3-4^3| \\ &=2|(x-4)(x^2+4x+4^2)|
\end{align}

So I stopped here and I don't know how to continue with the proof.

Comment: Pleas consider using MathJax in your questions. It improves legibility and allows us to understand your question better!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Consider the points $x=4$ and $4+h$ where $h$ goes to 0. Write down the difference quotient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a mistake when you write $|-2x^3 - 128| = 2|x^3-64|$. It should be $+64$ instead. That in mind, you have

\begin{align}|f(x)-f(a)| &= 2|x+4||x^2-4x + 16| = 2|x+4||(x+4)^2 - 12x|\\ &\leq 2|x+4|(|x+4|^2 + 12|x|).\end{align}

You know how to bound $|x+4| = |x-a|<\delta$, so the question is how to bound $|x|$.

Note that $$|x+4|<\delta \implies -\delta < x+4<\delta\implies -4-\delta < x < -4 + \delta$$ and we can always assume that $\delta < 4$ for simplicity (if you find some $\delta_0$ that should work, just choose $\delta=\min\{\delta_0,4\}$, you must have seen this). This gives us that $|x|<\delta + 4< 8$ and finally

$$|f(x) - f(a)| \leq 2\delta(\delta^2+12(\delta + 4)) < 224\delta$$

so you need to find $\delta$ such that $$224\delta<\varepsilon.\tag{1}$$

Comment: I understood now I'm very grateful sir

Comment: @Aliyu Marke, you are welcome. Also, take a look at Peter's answer, it's a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

Cf. User Ennar :

$|f(x)-f(a)|=$

$ 2|x+4||x^2-4x+16|=$

$2|x+4||(x-2)^2 +12|$.

Find a bound for the second factor:

Let $|x-(-4)| <1$, then

$-5<x <-3$, or $-7 <x -2<-5$;

implies $(x-2)^2 <49$.

Let $\epsilon$ be given.

Choose $\delta =\min(1,\epsilon/(122))$.

Then $|x+4|<\delta$ implies

$|f(x)-f(a)|= $

$2|x+4||((x-2)^2+12| \lt$

$2\delta (49 +12) = 122 \delta \le \epsilon$.